# create a stored procedure that compare all the attribut betwen them with sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

i want to create a stored procedure that compare all the attribut betwen them and if they are the same we insert them in a temp table and return it. This is a code that explains what i want:
if you want any other information please do not hesitate.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsTheSame]

    -- Liste des affaires à updater, au format '1,3,10'
    @ListeIdAffaires nvarchar(MAX),

    -- Infos à mettre à jour pour l'étape 'Préparation enlèvement'
    @date_demande_pretour date,
    @date_devis_mainteneur date,
    @date_go_derackage date,
    @date_post_tour_logistique date,
    @nom_fichier_pretour nvarchar(MAX),
    @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation bit,
    -- Infos à mettre à jour pour l'étape 'Mise à jour outil'
    @date_reprise_loueur_demandee date,
    @date_mail_gipi date,
    @num_palette nvarchar(MAX),
    @reference_reprise_loueur nvarchar(MAX),
    @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur date,
    @maj_outil_forcer_validation bit,
    -- Infos à mettre à jour pour l'étape 'Fin d'affaire'
    @date_restitution_au_loueur date,
    @date_sortie_parc date,
    @fin_affaire_forcer_validation bit

    AS

        -- On récupère le paramètre @ListeIdAffaires, une chaîne qui contient la liste des ids des affaires à modifier
        -- On transforme ce paramètre en une table temporaire contenant les valeurs
        -- Pour pouvoir faire le IN du update sur ces valeurs (pas possible de faire directement le IN sur @ListeIdAffaires dans le UPDATE, sinon risque d'injection SQL)
        CREATE TABLE    #AffairesIDs (AffaireID int);

        CREATE TABLE    #TempTable (date_demande_pretour date, date_devis_mainteneur date, date_go_derackage date, date_post_tour_logistique date, 
                        nom_fichier_pretour varchar(max), preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation bit, date_reprise_loueur_demandee date, date_mail_gipi date, 
                        num_palette nvarchar(MAX), reference_reprise_loueur nvarchar(MAX), date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur date, maj_outil_forcer_validation bit, 
                        date_restitution_au_loueur date, date_sortie_parc date, fin_affaire_forcer_validation bit);

        --variable pour voir le résultat retouorner par le test --
        DECLARE @isSame bit,
                @isEmpty nvarchar(2),
                @nom_fichier_pretour_temp nvarchar(MAX)

        DECLARE @requete nvarchar(max);
        SELECT @requete =
            'INSERT INTO #AffairesIDs(AffaireID)
             SELECT [id] FROM [Affaire] WHERE ([id] in (' + @ListeIdAffaires + '))';
        EXEC sp_executesql @requete;

        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            SET @isSame=1;
            SET @isEmpty='';

            DECLARE db_cursor_nom_fichier_pretour CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT  ISNULL(date_demande_pretour, GETDATE()), ISNULL(date_devis_mainteneur, GETDATE()), ISNULL(date_go_derackage, GETDATE()), 
                    ISNULL(date_post_tour_logistique, GETDATE()), ISNULL(nom_fichier_pretour, @isEmpty), ISNULL(preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation, 0), 
                    ISNULL(date_reprise_loueur_demandee, GETDATE()), ISNULL(date_mail_gipi, GETDATE()), ISNULL(num_palette, 0), ISNULL(reference_reprise_loueur, @isEmpty), 
                    ISNULL(date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur, GETDATE()), ISNULL(maj_outil_forcer_validation ,0), ISNULL(date_restitution_au_loueur ,GETDATE()), 
                    ISNULL(date_sortie_parc, GETDATE()), ISNULL(fin_affaire_forcer_validation, 0)
            FROM Affaire a, #AffairesIDs aID 
            WHERE a.id = aID.AffaireID;

            open db_cursor_nom_fichier_pretour;

            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_nom_fichier_pretour 
            INTO    @date_demande_pretour, @date_devis_mainteneur, @date_go_derackage, @date_post_tour_logistique, 
                    @nom_fichier_pretour, @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation, @date_reprise_loueur_demandee, @date_mail_gipi, @num_palette, @reference_reprise_loueur, 
                    @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur, @maj_outil_forcer_validation, @date_restitution_au_loueur, @date_sortie_parc, @fin_affaire_forcer_validation;

            -- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                   -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_nom_fichier_pretour 
            INTO    @date_demande_pretour, @date_devis_mainteneur, @date_go_derackage, @date_post_tour_logistique, 
                    @nom_fichier_pretour, @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation, @date_reprise_loueur_demandee, @date_mail_gipi, @num_palette, @reference_reprise_loueur, 
                    @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur, @maj_outil_forcer_validation, @date_restitution_au_loueur, @date_sortie_parc, @fin_affaire_forcer_validation;


////////////////////////////////////
/// --this is just one comparison with one attribute. i have to compare all the attributes 
/// in each row in the cursor
///////////////////////////////////
               IF ((@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) AND (@nom_fichier_pretour <> @nom_fichier_pretour_temp))
               BEGIN
                    SET @isSame = 0;
                    BREAK
               END
            END

            if(@isSame = 1)
                BEGIN
                    insert into #TempTable values (null, null, null, null, @nom_fichier_pretour, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                END
            else
                BEGIN
                    insert into #TempTable values (null, null, null, null, @isEmpty, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                END

            select * from #TempTable;

            CLOSE db_cursor_nom_fichier_pretour;
            DEALLOCATE db_cursor_nom_fichier_pretour;
        END

        DROP TABLE #AffairesIDs;

            DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

and when i call it, it returns this errors :

```
invoke operation 'IsTheSame' failed. The data reader is incompatible with the 'serverMonitoring.Affaire specified. a member with the type 'id' has no corresponding column in the data reader name of Member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of my probleme :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsTheSame]

@ListeIdAffaires nvarchar(MAX),
@date_demande_pretour date,
@date_devis_mainteneur date,
@date_go_derackage date,
@date_post_tour_logistique date,
@nom_fichier_pretour nvarchar(MAX),
@preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation bit,
@date_reprise_loueur_demandee date,
@date_mail_gipi date,
@num_palette nvarchar(MAX),
@reference_reprise_loueur nvarchar(MAX),
@date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur date,
@maj_outil_forcer_validation bit,
@date_restitution_au_loueur date,
@date_sortie_parc date,
@fin_affaire_forcer_validation bit

AS


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp;
CREATE TABLE    #Temp (date_demande_pretour date, date_devis_mainteneur date, date_go_derackage date, date_post_tour_logistique date, 
                nom_fichier_pretour varchar(max), preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation bit, date_reprise_loueur_demandee date, date_mail_gipi date, 
                num_palette nvarchar(MAX), reference_reprise_loueur nvarchar(MAX), date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur date, maj_outil_forcer_validation bit, 
                date_restitution_au_loueur date, date_sortie_parc date, fin_affaire_forcer_validation bit);

--temporory variable--
DECLARE @countOfRows int,
        @outDuplicateFound int,
        @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @Empty nvarchar(max),

        @date_demande_pretour_temp date,
        @date_devis_mainteneur_temp date,
        @date_go_derackage_temp date,
        @date_post_tour_logistique_temp date,
        @nom_fichier_pretour_temp nvarchar(MAX),
        @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation_temp bit,
        @date_reprise_loueur_demandee_temp date,
        @date_mail_gipi_temp date,
        @num_palette_temp nvarchar(MAX),
        @reference_reprise_loueur_temp nvarchar(MAX),
        @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur_temp date,
        @maj_outil_forcer_validation_temp bit,
        @date_restitution_au_loueur_temp date,
        @date_sortie_parc_temp date,
        @fin_affaire_forcer_validation_temp bit

DECLARE @requete nvarchar(max);
SELECT @requete =
            'INSERT INTO #Temp(date_demande_pretour, date_devis_mainteneur, date_go_derackage, 
            date_post_tour_logistique, nom_fichier_pretour, preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation, 
            date_reprise_loueur_demandee, date_mail_gipi, num_palette, reference_reprise_loueur, 
            date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur, maj_outil_forcer_validation , date_restitution_au_loueur , 
            date_sortie_parc, fin_affaire_forcer_validation)
    SELECT  [date_demande_pretour], [date_devis_mainteneur], [date_go_derackage], 
            [date_post_tour_logistique], [nom_fichier_pretour], [preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation], 
            [date_reprise_loueur_demandee], [date_mail_gipi], [num_palette], [reference_reprise_loueur], 
            [date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur], [maj_outil_forcer_validation] , [date_restitution_au_loueur] , 
            [date_sortie_parc], [fin_affaire_forcer_validation]
    FROM    [Affaire]
    WHERE   ([id] in (' + @ListeIdAffaires + '))';
EXEC sp_executesql @requete;

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @Empty='';

    SELECT @countOfRows=COUNT(*) FROM #Temp;

    Select  Top 1 @date_demande_pretour = #Temp.date_demande_pretour, @date_devis_mainteneur = #Temp.date_devis_mainteneur, @date_go_derackage = #Temp.date_go_derackage, 
            @date_post_tour_logistique = #Temp.date_post_tour_logistique, @nom_fichier_pretour = #Temp.nom_fichier_pretour, 
            @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation = #Temp.preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation, @date_reprise_loueur_demandee = #Temp.date_reprise_loueur_demandee,
            @date_mail_gipi = #Temp.date_mail_gipi, @num_palette = #Temp.num_palette, @reference_reprise_loueur = #Temp.reference_reprise_loueur, 
            @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur = #Temp.date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur, @maj_outil_forcer_validation = #Temp.maj_outil_forcer_validation , 
            @date_restitution_au_loueur = #Temp.date_restitution_au_loueur , @date_sortie_parc = #Temp.date_sortie_parc, @fin_affaire_forcer_validation = #Temp.fin_affaire_forcer_validation
    From #Temp;

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_demande_pretour,'')=COALESCE(@date_demande_pretour,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_demande_pretour_temp = @date_demande_pretour;
                --select * from Affaire where Affaire.date_demande_pretour = @date_demande_pretour_temp;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_demande_pretour_temp = '';
                --select * from Affaire where Affaire.date_demande_pretour = @date_demande_pretour_temp;
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_devis_mainteneur,'')=COALESCE(@date_devis_mainteneur,''));
        IF(@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_devis_mainteneur_temp = @date_devis_mainteneur;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_devis_mainteneur_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_go_derackage,'')=COALESCE(@date_go_derackage,''));
        IF(@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_go_derackage_temp = @date_go_derackage;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_go_derackage_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_post_tour_logistique,'')=COALESCE(@date_post_tour_logistique,''));
        IF(@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_post_tour_logistique_temp = @date_post_tour_logistique;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_post_tour_logistique_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.nom_fichier_pretour,'')=COALESCE(@nom_fichier_pretour,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @nom_fichier_pretour_temp = @nom_fichier_pretour;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @nom_fichier_pretour_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation,'')=COALESCE(@preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation_temp = @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @preparation_enlevement_forcer_validation_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_reprise_loueur_demandee,'')=COALESCE(@date_reprise_loueur_demandee,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_reprise_loueur_demandee_temp = @date_reprise_loueur_demandee;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_reprise_loueur_demandee_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_mail_gipi,'')=COALESCE(@date_mail_gipi,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_mail_gipi_temp = @date_mail_gipi;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_mail_gipi_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.num_palette,'')=COALESCE(@num_palette,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @num_palette_temp = @num_palette;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @num_palette_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.reference_reprise_loueur,'')=COALESCE(@reference_reprise_loueur,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @reference_reprise_loueur_temp = @reference_reprise_loueur;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @reference_reprise_loueur_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur,'')=COALESCE(@date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur_temp = @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_mail_envoi_reprise_loueur_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.maj_outil_forcer_validation,'')=COALESCE(@maj_outil_forcer_validation,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @maj_outil_forcer_validation_temp = @maj_outil_forcer_validation;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @maj_outil_forcer_validation_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_restitution_au_loueur,'')=COALESCE(@date_restitution_au_loueur,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_restitution_au_loueur_temp = @date_restitution_au_loueur;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_restitution_au_loueur_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.date_sortie_parc,'')=COALESCE(@date_sortie_parc,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @date_sortie_parc_temp = @date_sortie_parc;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @date_sortie_parc_temp = '';
            END

    SET @outDuplicateFound = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE COALESCE(#Temp.fin_affaire_forcer_validation,'')=COALESCE(@fin_affaire_forcer_validation,''));
        IF (@outDuplicateFound = @countOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @fin_affaire_forcer_validation_temp = @fin_affaire_forcer_validation;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @fin_affaire_forcer_validation_temp = '';
            END

        SELECT * FROM #Temp;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for updating your table...if so look at this...else please clarify your conditions

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTable 
DECLARE 
@var1 //your type
@var2 // your type
AS
IF EXISTS(item1 = @var1 AND item2 = @var2)//It already exist
BEGIN
UPDATE Table
Set Field1 = @var1,
    Field2 = @var2
WHERE item1 = @var1 AND item2 = @var2
END
ELSE// insert it if it doesn't
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table
VALUES(@var1,@var2...)
END
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. no i don't want to update my table, what i want to do is :
first i get the ids of the element that i want to modify and return all attributs in a curseur and compare all the element for exemple :
IF ((@nom_fichier_pretour = @nom_fichier_pretour_temp))
and i have to do that for every "nom_fichier_pretour_temp" in the cursor and if they are the same i have to insert that attribut in a temp table else i insert a null.i have to do that for all the attributs to post it in a view "if an attribut is the same then i post it else i post nothing"